# Issues with serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is when i submit the form with the click event. The click event is triggered in 
the click event I use `$('#form_id').serialize();` to fetch the form details.

Just before serialize function is called I update some form fields using JavaScript/jQuery.

After which I call serialize and then I call AJAX post.

But when I check the post values in the console. I noticed that the form fields that get updated before the call of serialize event they do not get reflected in the serialize variables.

Therefore my question is how can I refresh the serialize variable to get the latest values on the form.

Update - 
I have added a bind event on certain events. If i use a set timeout event and then call the serialize functions. Then the changes updated  in the form get returned correctly in the serialize event.

Is there a way I can make the bind event return a value so that I do not have to call a set time out event. and then

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: Aren't you calling serialize() before?! Provide relevant code in question